# Заставить cURL ждать, пока страница не загрузится полностью

Tags: php, curl

Работаю с API данных, который после моего запроса к нему собирает данные 2-4 секунды. Но cURL в PHP делает запрос и выводит мне лишь малую часть тех данных, которые даёт мне API. Насколько я понимаю, cURL не дожидается полной загрузки данных, а делает запрос, выводит полученные данные и сразу же закрывает соединение. Можно ли как-то научить cURL ждать, пока страница не загрузится полностью?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/flight_search_results?uuid=" . $id);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$tickets = curl_exec($ch);
echo json_encode(json_decode($tickets, true), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Вообще, обычно он дожидается конца соединения, такое ощущение, что это API делает вывод странным образом. Попробуйте https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_pause.html - вдруг это то, что вам нужно

Comment: @Станислав там, похоже, динамический вывод данных используется. А можно как-то устроить стриминговую загрузку данных, например? Чтобы получать данные по мере их поступления.

Comment: А API не ваш, я верно понял? Про вывод - да, тем же php можно так выводить контент, сбрасывая буфер вывода через `ob_flush()` или типа того.

Comment: @Станислав да, API не мой. Но, кажется, я понял в чём причина. Там, значит, вот как всё работает. Я сперва отправляю на сервер запрос с нужными мне данными. На них генерируется нужный мне вывод, за которым мне нужно обратиться ещё раз. Но делать это нужно с задержкой, поскольку сбор данных может занимать разное количество времени, как я уже говорил. От 1 до 5 секунд.

Comment: Ну то есть указанная мной функция поможет? Которая про паузу?